# "Isn't either" and "Neither is"

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

I wonder whether in the example below:

- > Peter isn't here today. **Martha isn't either.**

Can we substitute the second sentence for "**Neither is Martha**"?

I'm asking this question because once I read in Practical English Usage by "Michael Swan" that one cannot use "neither" here as an exception. (I can't exactly recall the rule!) While we can say:

> Peter didn't pass the exam. **Neither did Martha.** as well as "**Martha didn't either**."

Please kindly enlighten me.

Comment: I think you must have either misunderstood or are misremembering something from Swann. Your *one cannot use "neither" here as an exception* doesn't tie up with anything I can see in my PDF 3rd edition of *Practical English Usage*, nor does it mean anything to me as a native speaker. In practice, we normally use ***neither + [verb]*** rather than ***either + NOT + [verb]***, but both forms are perfectly acceptable in contexts like your example.

Comment: What about "Martha neither" @FumbleFingers Reinstate Monica?

Comment: I'd say that ***Me neither*** is perfectly common (though *personally*, I'd usually say ***Nor me***, and punctilious pedants might prefer ***Nor I***). But for ***non-pronoun*** contexts, [nobody much likes the "neither" version.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=nor+John%2CJohn+neither&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnor%20John%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CJohn%20neither%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: Well @FumbleFingers Reinstate Monica thank you, but I think: "**pronoun + neither**" works, as in: > - "I don't like tea. Me neither." While using it along with a "proper noun" like: > - "Martha neither." (**Name + neither**) would sound a bit off. Do you confirm my take on it?

Comment: That is what I meant by my previous comment, yes. But thinking about it again now, I shouldn't have used the word "pronoun". So far as I'm concerned, the *only* relatively idiomatic version is ***Me neither*** (I dislike ***You / Him / Us / They neither*** as much as ***John neither***). Perhaps the *specific* case of first person singular is influenced by people (consciously ***or*** unconsciously) sidestepping that tiresome choice between ***Nor me*** and ***Nor I***, I dunno.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can say "**Neither is Martha**".

In one of the most recent news about Buttigieg replying to Biden, you can read the following (please check the full text [here](https://thehill.com/homenews/sunday-talk-shows/482211-buttigieg-biden-is-right-that-im-no-barack-obama-but-neither-is-he)):

> Buttigieg: Biden is right that I'm no Barack Obama, but '**neither is he**'

I believe that Buttigieg speaks proper English and he uses "**neither is he**" in his answer.

Comment: Thank you @Anatolii, but may I ask you for which dialect are you speaking?